# Magento Marketplace extension Installation & Varnish Test failed composer memory limit error

Tags: magento2, module, marketplace

I am trying to upload one module in Magento Marketplace but in technical review the Installation & Varnish Test is failed 
http://prntscr.com/mr5lt5

when I view the report then I see below error.
http://prntscr.com/mr5mgg

Environment: PHP 5.6.37 Magento 2.1 CE

composer require insider/module-integration:1.0.0 2>&1

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class

The following exception is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details

PHP Warning:  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 959

Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 959

[ErrorException]                                   
proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
```

How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

there are two possibility here

1. Looks like you runs out of swap memory,
   try this

> ```
> /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
>
> /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
>
> /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
> ```

this solution was described in [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898#issuecomment-23453850)

2. A bit old but just in case someone new is looking for a solution, updating your PHP version can fix the issue.

   Also you should be committing your composer.lock file and doing a composer 
    install on a production environment which is less resource intensive.

More details [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898#issuecomment-23453850):

Comment: OK but issue happening when magento marketplace automatic testing for Installation & Varnish Test Results not on our server
http://prntscr.com/mr6zyf

Comment: you can memory limit increase in your server also composer latest update Ref: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18119465/10748606

Comment: also check it : http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2016/proc-error-installing-with-composer/

Comment: **can you, who downvoted, please explain your reasoning**

Comment: @VDC you can contact Marketplace team may be they can help you

Comment: Yes I already contacted them and they said its their side issue http://prntscr.com/mrnnuy

Comment: then good news for vdc side